# What is the fastest way to create integer domain?

Tags: java

I have tried to build domain with integer ranges but excluding one point in this range. For example, I should build a range until 4, from always zero. However, I must exclude one point in it say 3. Therefore, my domain should look like array [0,1,2,4]. What is the fastest way to create integer domain?

Comment: > . What is the fastest way to create integer domain?

What have you tried?

Comment: @J-Dizzle I have tried to construct it with naive iteration method. Go over each number until 4, if 3 is encountered, do not update the domain array; otherwise, add number to domain array.

Comment: And what went wrong? Did it look like Debasis' solution? Because that looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8:

```
final int start = ...;
final int endInclusive = ...;
final int exclude = ...;
int[] domain = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, endInclusive).
        filter(i -> i != exclude).
        toArray();
```

i.e. create an `IntStream` `[start, endInclusive]` then filter out the value you want to exclude and finally collect it to an array.

As a method:

```
public int[] createDomain(final int start, final int endInclusive, final int exclude) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(start, endInclusive).
            filter(i -> i != exclude).
            toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an arraylist of integeres in your domain leaving out one specific element. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> domain = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
createDomain(domain, 1, 4, 3);

...
void createDomain(domain, int start, int end, int leaveOutElement) {
    int i;
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (i == leaveOutElement)
            continue;
        domain.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst logically correct this won't compile. Also, why pass in a collection to populate it? That seems odd - create the collection in the method and return it. The method is called `_create_Domain` after all...